# Is it possible to access the current browser url from a Facebook Page Tab iframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-page

I have a facebook page tab iframe and would like to access the browser url in order to get the current facebook page url.

I know it's not possible to use a javascript that interacts with the parent frame because of browser security issues.

An approach that didn't work for all browsers was to read the **HTTP_REFERER** header from the request.

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is impossible at all. Otherwise it will be a security issue, likely to be closed.

You should not write code depending on compromising other users.

Comment: If this is impossible, then you cannot run an application that is SSL only in Facebook (because you cannot redirect from HTTP to HTTPS)

Comment: there is no limitation for an redirect see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to get URL of a parent Frame due to cross-domain policy. And there is no way to get the information about page your application running on in client-side.

But on the server-side you can reconstruct the Page URL using details passed in [`signed_request`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/). For Page Tab Applications it contains `page`:

> A JSON object containing the page `id` `string`, the `liked` `boolean` (set to `true` if the user has liked the page, `false` if not) and the `admin` `boolean` (set to `true` if the user is an admin of the page, `false` if they're not).

Using that page id you can build the Page URL:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/-/PAGE_ID
```

If you want the link to your Page Tab with your application use:

```
http://www.facebook.com/pages/-/PAGE_ID?v=app_APPLICATION_ID
```

Beware, `HTTP_REFERRER` is provided by client and cannot be trusted, and it's may be cut by plugin/proxy/etc...

**Notes:**
Pages may have different URL in real life, but using this technique user will be landing the correct Page since Facebook will issue redirect to correct URL of a Page.
Sample URLs use `HTTP` scheme, feel free to use `HTTPS` if you need it.

In PHP for example you can detect the current scheme like this:

```php
$scheme = ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS']!=="off") ||
           (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) &&
            $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']=="https")
          ) ? 'https' : 'http';
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the redirection you purpose only works if the protocol is HTTP.

Comment: Well, I've provided a sample URLs feel free to replace `HTTP` to `HTTPS` (it will work as expected as well), you may detect the currently user scheme and use it instead of using hard-coded protocol scheme...

Comment: https://www.facebook.com/pages/-/PAGE_ID?v=app_APPLICATION_ID (HTTPS) is redirected to http://www.facebook.com/pages/-/PAGE_ID?v=app_APPLICATION_ID (HTTP)

Comment: @barbolo, this is only the case for unauthorized users. For authorized users Facebook preserve Account Security Settings (if user have enabled secure browsing he will land the `HTTPS` server page).

Answer (score 0):

HTTP_REFERRER might not work as expected in my experience. If the tab app is designed for a specific page (which I suppose it kind of should), have you tried recreating it?

https://www.facebook.com/MYPAGENAME/app_MYAPPID

Where MYPAGENAME is your page name and MYAPPID is the app id, of course.

If the tab is applied to multiple pages though, I'm quite sure you'll get the relevant data to apply the above from https://graph.facebook.com/PAGEID, where PAGEID is the ID of the page which you get from the [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).