# how to redirect https requests to http

Tags: apache, http, https

I have a site on my machine (localy).
Users used to access it using both HTTP and HTTPS. Now there is a problem with HTTPS configuration.[ It is not working]
**Is it possible to redirect HTTPS requests to the HTTP port temporarly?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http)

Comment: @MaVRoSCy  it is apache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your .htaccess file paste this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I am using Apache where can i find my ht-access file?

Comment: /etc/apache2/sites-available/default or create a new file in the root directory of you website, /.htaccess.

Comment: create .htaccess file in the root directory of your website

Comment: so am i expected to only put this content to htaccess or it has addition content