# Apache Https to Http Redirect

Tags: apache, ssl

I currently have a website that use to have an SSL so the web address started with https://

I moved the website to a new server and platform which doesn't have an SSL so the web address starts with http://

I have inbound links going to the https address that I am wanting to redirect to the new website http url. Is this possible without me having to reinstall a new SSL on the new server? Is so, what could a possible solution be?

I have searched and found some promising stuff, but nothing worked. The hosting account is running on Cpanel v11.38.2 and Apache v2.2.23. Thank you for any insight, it is greatly appreciated!

Regards

Comment: To accept an HTTPS connection even only to return a redirect, you must still accept HTTPS connections in the first place, which means you need HTTPS installed and turned-on, either with a real certificate or a self-signed one. Right?

Comment: Start by making Apache to listen to port 443 besides port 80. See if you can at least display static files through that. If presented with certificate errors, you'll have to resort to self signed certs which will display a warning to the visitor.

Comment: @amenadiel You can't just serve plain-text HTTP on port 443, the browser will bail out as soon as it realises you're not speaking the right language.

Comment: @bzlm Add that as an answer and I'll upvote it. It's really all there is to say.

Comment: @bzlm      Me2:).....

Comment: I usually leave answering to the young'uns these days, but wth. @IMSoP

Answer (score 2):

To accept an HTTPS connection even only to return a redirect, you must still accept HTTPS connections in the first place, which means you need HTTPS installed and turned-on, either with a real certificate or a self-signed one.

For details on how to achieve the actual redirection, perhaps this question can help you: [How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http)