# Add code to apache to correctly redirect http to https

Tags: apache, redirect

I'm having problems to automatically redirect http to https. For example: if I type http://blog.mysite.com it redirects to https://blog.mysite.com it redirects correctly. But if I type http://blog.racheaqui.com.br/wp-admin/ it redirects incorrectly to https://blog.racheaqui.com.brwp-admin/. What should I add to apache config file to solve this?

I currently manage my http to https redirect using the following code in each subdomain config file (for example: /etc/apache2/sites-available/005-blog.mysite.com.conf):

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName blog.mysite.com
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/blog.mysite.com
Redirect permanent / https://blog.mysite.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: If your going to use https make sure all urls in your systems use https.

Comment: Please show us your redirect / rewrite code so we can help you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http)

Comment: Please have a look at this site for information about how to redirect http to https, there are plenty already.