# htaccess redirect not preserving protocol

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have a rule set up in `.htaccess` to add a trailing slash, but if the host is `https`, this causes it to redirect via `http`, but I don't understand why:

```
# add trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$
RewriteRule .* /%1/ [R=301,L]
```

So, if I request `https://www.example.com/some/page` it triggers the rule in `.htaccess` to add the trailing slash, but redirects me to `http://www.example.com/some/page/`.

If a page is requested as **https:**//www.example.com/some/page, why is the rule above redirecting it to **http:**//www.example.com/some/page/?

How can I add the trailing slash while still redirecting with the correct host?

Comment: Can't you just add a trailing slash in your redirect?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489895/http-to-https-through-htaccess

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http)

Comment: Your PHP code is not looking right, why do you need this if you can handle `http->https` via rewrite rules itself.

Comment: Rewrite is not redirecting `https` to `http`. If you mix redirection logic in code and rule then it will indeed cause problems like this.

Comment: @anubhava it appears to be. If I remove the rule it works fine. If I add the rule and look at network requests it redirects `https://www.example.com/some/page` to `http://www.example.com/some/page/`, so irrespective of the redirect in the code itself, the problem lies within the `.htaccess` rule

Comment: You're totally mistaken here. Your rule is not making it `http` but it is your shown PHP that is doing it. Remove all PHP code and test it separately.

Comment: @anubhava I'm not - I see the php redirect as a separate request in the network tab, which redirects to the homepage (if you look at the php above, it redirects to the homepage, not to `/some/page`)

Comment: If you want to waste your time in arguing it is fine but if I were you I would have tested the rules separately (without any PHP support). btw I have already tested your shown rule in my Apache (without any PHP code) and there is no `https->http` redirection.

Comment: I'm not arguing, you're adamant that my php redirect is at fault here when it's clearly not. You can see from the code I've provided, and the comments above that this cannot be the case. Thanks for helping anyway.

Comment: I am only adamant that shown rewrite rule is not doing `https->http` conversion and I have already tested that before writing any comment.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just modify your rule to this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/([A-Za-z0-9\-\/]*[A-Za-z0-9\-]+)$
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/ [R=301,L]
```

This would also force the use of *HTTPS* which is always a good thing. : )

Comment: because the code/htaccess is shared by numerous sites, some of which need to be served via `https`, some `http`

Comment: You can put it on the subdirectory responsible for the specific website.

Comment: It's not really a feasable solution. There are maybe 10 sites which are served via https, that'd mean adding and maintaing 10 separate `.htaccess` files. I don't understand why the rule is redirecting `https` to `http`