# HTTPS to HTTP redirect not working HTTPS loading different websites data

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I've got a strange problem with https not redirecting to http. I need https://indudlgeinbrighton.co.uk to redirect to http://indulgeinbrighton.co.uk It's on a shared server and I'm getting a strange cross over with the https. When https is put in, it's loading information for a completely different website hosted on the server.

https://indulgeinbrighton.co.uk is the URL affected. I don't normally share the URLs I'm working on, but in the case I think it might be helpful to see what's going on. Where it's showing data for a website called Churchill, obviously this is a bit of a problem. I've tried putting in all the solutions provided on this page [How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http) into the root .htaccess but it's not working. The htaccess is working fine, because when I switched it to load the other way from http to https it worked fine.

I can only assume it's reading the htaccess file from the other site when it's looking at the https version. As I know which site it is, that's easy enough to locate, but what could I put in that htaccess file to redirect this particular url query without affecting https redirects on the other site?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in your .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 443 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://indulgeinbrighton.co.uk/$1 [R,L]
```

Comment: Exellent that did the trick, but it needed to be added to the .htaccess file of the churchillbrighton.com directorty, not it's own. Thank you for your help. Saved me a big headache.

Comment: Hi, just wondering if you knew how to make this work for all pages of the site? This only seems to have fixed the home page? Thanks agan

Answer (score 0):

this is for security measure

> The page at 'https://indulgeinbrighton.co.uk/' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure script
>   'http://churchillbrighton.com/wp-content/themes/brighton-hotels/js/avia.js?ver=3'.
>   This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

you can try to do this in PHP

```
$protocol = isset($_SERVER["HTTPS"]) ? 'https' : 'http';
```

or include always external files in https

Comment: sorry, variable $protocol must be placed before every exteneral file like this <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?=$protocol?>://mysite.com/styles.min.css" />

Comment: Sorry not sure I follow what you're trying to get me to do. I don't want to load the https, or any content from churchill. I want the https:// induldgeinbrighton.co.uk to redirect to http:// indulgeinbrighton.co.uk