# How to redirect https links to http?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

Recently I've moved my blog from wordpress.com to my personal hosting. For some reason all of my links indexed on Google results and also the ones that I have listed on Reddit forums shows this error:

*Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from rockiceland.com (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID*

I believe the main reason for that is **https** in front of the links. I haven't purchased SSL certificate, it is something that Wordpress.com included and should have been gone after the migration of the blog (i think?).

If I try to access internal links with **http**, it opens as normal.

Have you an idea how could I fix it so all the **https** would redirect to **http** links?

Comment: WordPress.com switched to HTTPS a while back. If you're now running a site without an SSL certificate you'll need to 1) update your links and 2) setup a redirect as you've already identified. I'd consider keeping HTTPS and purchasing an SSL certificate instead.

Comment: Agree with @NathanDawson in considering TLS as a long term quality solution. Anymore the process has been simplified by services like [LetsEncrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)(free!). Additioanlly, and this may be unimportant, but HTTPS is preferred in Google Search rank, as they're trying to encourage a broad adoption of encryption. [Google Security Blog](https://security.googleblog.com/2016/09/moving-towards-more-secure-web.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you're now working from your own host, using a mod_rewrite could help here.

This question has been brought up before and had an excellent discussion and answers that approach this type of http re-write on several different configs:

[How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http)

If still using WP as the blogs CMS there may be a plugin to simplify the process, I was able to find this one that seems quite promising: [Mavis HTTPS to HTTP Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/mavis-https-to-http-redirect/)