# How to redirect https request to http in magento?

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect, magento-1.9

My magento site is loading well on `http` request, http://my-magento-site.com. But when I try lo load using https://my-magento-site.com It redirect to an error page, https://my-magento-site.com/cgi-sys/defaultwebpage.cgi . How do I prevent this, and redirect to `http` request ?

I tried to add this code on my root `.htaccess` file but not redirect,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

How do I fix this ?

Comment: Hope this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http

Comment: You should never redirect from https to http. Fix the issue instead.

Answer (score 0):

If **.htaccess Rewrite rule is not working then** you can set this by magento settings.
**Goto >> system >> configuration >> web**{under general tab}
You will find unsecure and secure tabs.
Write 
       **Base URL**         http://my-magento-site.com       in both URLs. 
    **You will always redirect to http:// only**