# Adding HTTPS forcing to my .htaccess file

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have an `.htaccess` file the includes some rewrites that are doing a couple of things, which is working fine. It looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On

# Removes .php ending from path
# ---------------

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.php [L]

# Services & Knowledgebase rewrites
# ---------------

RewriteRule ^services/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /services.php?cat=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^services/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /services.php?service=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^knowledge-base/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /knowledge-base.php?cat=$1&s=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^knowledge-base/([a-zA-Z0-9-/]+)$ /knowledge-base.php?cat=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

I have now added SSL to the site, and need to force HTTPS for the entire site. I have tried adding the following to my `.htaccess`:

```
# Force HTTPS
# ---------------

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Just after the `RewriteEngine On` statement, however when I try `example.com`, the url remains as `example.com` and I get the following:

> #### Not Found
>
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.

If I go to `https://example.com` it works perfectly.

**How do I force the https correctly, while retaining my other rewrite rules?**

Thanks for any help

Mike

Comment: Duplicate topic. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http/39074632#39074632

Comment: Hi - I don't think it is a duplicate. That post is about forcing **to** http from https, and does not include anything about working with additional rewrites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I usually use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Never ran into any issues with that.