# Force redirect https to http after expire ssl

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, ssl, https

My `SSL` certificate and `dedicated IP` expired last night, and my site won't works anymore with `https` now i decided somehow to keep going with `http` and redirect all `https` to `http` well, i know there is so many solution in `google` like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R]
```

And tried and read all these topics:

[How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http)

[Https to http redirect using htaccess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12999910/https-to-http-redirect-using-htaccess)

or similar answers but non of these solve my problem, and i still get this browser error:

> ### This site can’t provide a secure connection
>
> example.com sent an invalid response.
>
> ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

```
Server: Apache
CMS: Open Cart
Host: Shared
```

I turned off `ssl` configuration in setting of `opencart` and in `config.php` i change:

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://example.com/');
```

**To:**

```
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://example.com/');
```

But still same error. I have many user and indexed page in google, any solution to solve this? i need to solve this A.S.A.P.

**How can i *force* redirect `https` to `http`?**

Comment: why dont you renew the cert?

Comment: Long story, i want to migrate from a shared host, to a VPS soon, and for now i want to keep site live until i migrate @nogad

Comment: not sure why that makes any difference

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Explanation :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
```

Checks if the HTTPS is on (Request is made using https)

Then

```
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Comment: still same, `This site can’t provide a secure connection`

Comment: i have updated my Answer, try that.

Comment: still same.. look like this rule not read at all.