# What is OrientDB's DocumentRoot? Or, where are OrientDB's web files?

Tags: apache, https, orientdb

I am attempting to access OrientDB's REST API through a reverse proxy. That is, I have a domain orientdb.mydomain.com that forwards to localhost:2480, where the server is. I have this working on the unsecured website, so I can access http://orientdb.mydomain.com and it brings up the studio site:

http://orientdb.mydomain.com/studio/index.html

However, this does not work through https. I get a 404 error ("The requested URL /studio/index.html was not found on this server")

I have a feeling that I'm not using the correct documentroot or there is something funny about OrientDB that it's generating the path above in another way. I cannot actually find this /studio directory anywhere.

This is from my virtualhost setting in my ssl.conf file.

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>                                                                                    
DocumentRoot "/opt/orientdb-3.0.6/www"
<Directory "/opt/orientdb-3.0.6/www">

        Require all granted
    </Directory>

ServerName orientdb.mydomain.com
#more stuff
</VirtualHost>
```

By the way, I originally had the following options in my Directory tag, but it gave a forbidden error. I changed it to Require all granted and it now says not found- so I think I'm making progress.

```
    AllowOverride All                                                                                                                                   
    Order allow,deny
```

In summary, is it possible to access the OrientDB server in this way and if so what do I put as DocumentRoot, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out not to be an OrientDB issue, but a proxy issue. I had used a virtualhost to set up the proxy on port 80, but I did not do the same for port 443. After adding these settings to my 443 virtualhost on orientdb.mydomain.com, I was able to access the studio and the HTTP REST API through HTTPS.

```
ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:2480/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:2480/

<Proxy *>
       Require all granted
</Proxy>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that. 
OrientDB has its own HTTP server embedded so the only way it can work is with the reverse proxy configuration.

You can expose your web server (apache HTTP I guess) in https and terminate the "s" there, proxying to orientdb HTTP port (2480).

Comment: Thanks.  I'm not terribly familiar with setting up a web server. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "You can expose your web server (apache HTTP I guess) in https and terminate the "s" there, proxying to orientdb HTTP port (2480)."? It sounds like you mean forward the https request to http but I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Do you mean something along these lines? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http