# Tell browser to not point to https anymore but http now

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, https

My problem is a little bit similar to this [How do you redirect HTTPS to HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371/how-do-you-redirect-https-to-http) but in my case, browsers seem to not point no more to my server when typing `https://mydomain`. So the sample code suggested for `.htaccess` for redirection cant help.

PS: `http://mydomain` works  !

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the request to `https://mydomain` does not actually go to your server (or any system that you have control over), then you can not rewrite it anywhere else either. But if the HTTP version works, then something must be messed up with your configuration - the DNS does not care for the protocol, so resolving the domain name `mydomain` should result in the same IP address in either case. It is not really clear what the _actual_ problem is here, so you will need to give us some more info.

Comment: 1. manually check the DNS resolution using a utility like `dig`, `host` or `nslookup`. 2. check if the port for https is open at all at the server using the `telnet` utility (or `nmap` or similar). 3. check the different host configurations for the http and the https host for a difference.